# What is the difference between null and (type)null?

Tags: c#, casting, null

**Note:**
THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219501/cast-null-value-to-a-type) asks why it is even possible to cast a null, my question is what is the difference between `null` and `(type)null` to begin with.

---

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) reference  (from the MSDN C# reference), it is said that this code:

```
expression as type
```

is equivalent to this code ("except that the `expression` variable is evaluated only one time"):

```
expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null
```

It made me wonder, what's the point of the null casting? How is this different from:

```
expression is type ? (type)expression : null
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast null value to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219501/cast-null-value-to-a-type)

Comment: The documentation states `The code is equivalent to` keyword being `equivalent`. You could remove the cast and the result would be the same as that is also equivalent to `expression as type` but why mention every possible functional equivalency?

Comment: `null` can be any type. But if you want a null string, you have to cast `null` to `string`. If you assign your expression to a `var x`, the compiler doesn't know which type `x` should be, if the assignment results in `null`.  Therefore the cast.

Comment: @Emaro `null` can be implicitly converted to any nullable type, so long as the context provides the type to convert it ti. In this case, the `(type)expression` provides sufficient context.

Comment: @Igor - Thanks! But is `(type)null` equivalent to `null`? If yes, why the redundancy?

Comment: @hvd, yes. However if you have some inheritance hierarchy or tupels, the type cannot always be guessed by the compiler.

Comment: @Reniuz - Please review my edit.

Comment: The `null` value doesn't have a type, but the `null` expression might be given a type by an explicit cast, so here: `(type)null` is an expression with a type that will result in a value that doesn't have a type. The type is used by the compiler in overload resolution and similar, but once you are left with the actual value, the type disappears.

Comment: In the case of the ternary operator in this question, in this case it doesn't matter, since `null` can be safely cast to any specific reference type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this example project:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Error: The call is ambigious between the following methods or properties: ShowMessage(FirstClass), ShowMessage(SecondClass)
    ShowMessage(null);
    //Here it is known which type is being used
    ShowMessage((FirstClass)null);
}

private static void ShowMessage(FirstClass value)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(value);
}

private static void ShowMessage(SecondClass value)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
}

class FirstClass { }
class SecondClass { }
```

Therefor, `null` and `(FirstClass)null` is not the same. With `(FirstClass)null` you define it explicitly as the nullable type `FirstClass` (`class` is nullable as reference type) that is null. The other `null` is just ... well `null` and must be cast implicitly to the needed nullable type.

Beware:
If you'd replace

```
ShowMessage(NotFirstClassObj as FirstClass)
```

with

```
ShowMessage(NotFirstClassObj is Firstclass ? (FirstClass)NotFirstClassObj : null)
```

It still works because the compiler can still derive the correct type. But this may be the reason why it's `(type)null` in the documentary.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states `The code is equivalent to` keyword being `equivalent`. You could remove the cast and the result would be the same as that is also equivalent to `expression as type` but why mention every possible functional equivalency?

---

> what is the difference between `null` and `(type)null` to begin with

There is no difference in this case. They equate to the same thing. The author *probably* chose to use `(type)null` because it more clearly conveys how `as` works.