# How to get the Type of an object that is a Nullable<Int> when the value is null

Tags: c#, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET : How do you get the Type of a null object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254461/net-how-do-you-get-the-type-of-a-null-object)

Basically I would like code like one of the following to work without a null reference error:

```
int? i1 = default(int?);
int? i2 = new Nullable<Int32>();
int? i3 = new int?();
var t1 = i1.GetType();
var t2 = i2.GetType();
var t3 = i3.GetType();
```

I would hope/expect that I would be able to obtain the type from the **i** objects above without a null reference exception.

If this is not possible, how would I be able to create a reference to a Nullable Int while maintaining a null value.

**UPDATE:** for those interested and don't want to sift through the not totally applicable answers in the linked question, the solution is:

```
private void Example()
{
    var i = default(int?);
    var t = this.GetDeclaredType(i);
}

private Type GetDeclaredType<T>(T obj)
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```

Comment: Short version: you cannot. An empty `Nullable<T>` boxes to `null`. And `null` *does not have a type*. Calling `.GetType()` requires boxing.

Comment: Added solution which was derived from the linked question.