# C# get member's type ignoring it's value?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, member

How can I get a **Type** of member, ignoring its **value** ?

```
public static class Program
{

    public static String a {set; get;}

    public static void Main()
    {
         a = null;
         a.GetType(); //Cant do that, it's null, how can i get "String"?
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to declare the variable before using it.

Comment: @AsadAli what do you mean?

Comment: The variable `a` hasn't been declared, so you can't use it. If you try to use the `a` property, it won't return anything.

Comment: @AsadAli It's a property...

Comment: well it is compilable, apart from a.GetType(); witch i commented

Comment: `A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a private field.` The property points to nothing and if compiled as the code is, it throws a `NullReferenceException`. Isn't that wrong?

Comment: @AsadAli https://dotnetfiddle.net/b7ZR6M well what do you say to this ali?

Comment: well that's what i wrote in comments, i DO require a solution using reflections -.- it's in the tags man

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254461/net-how-do-you-get-the-type-of-a-null-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to get it's type without an instance is using the declaring type:

```
var type = typeof(Program)
     .GetProperty("a", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
     .PropertyType;
```

Comment: this is nice, can i do that without acessing member with string, but using the member's reference itself instead?

Comment: Or, can i get referenced member's name?

Comment: @user3325976: Yes you can, using a lambda (instead of `a`, write `() => a`) and an expression tree.

Comment: @BenVoigt that would be very nice, could you show me how?

Comment: @user3325976: I marked this as a duplicate of a question and answer showing you how to get the `PropertyInfo`.  Then just get the `PropertyType` from the `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: @BenVoigt no, i meant the lambda expression

Comment: @user3325976: Yeah, the accepted answer on that other question shows a lambda expression, and getting the `PropertyInfo` from it.