# Get type of object parameter in generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following piece of code

```
    public TOutput DoStuff<TOutput>(object input)
    {
        var type = typeof(IDoStuffHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TOutput), input.GetType());

        dynamic provider = _lifetimeScope.Resolve(type);

        return provider.DoStuff((dynamic)input);
    }
```

This currently works as long as the input is not null. As soon as we have a null I get a null reference exception on input.GetType(). Is there a way for me to figure out the type of input?

Comment: No way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254461/net-how-do-you-get-the-type-of-a-null-object

Comment: No this does not solve the question as it is not the same. The output parameter is different than what we use as input. This method converts types to different types

Comment: how are they different? you just added a resolvable type next to the null type. They BOTH need to be resolved independently.